# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348 : starting container process caused "no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to bringup my fabric network. 
I got my orderers organization started. 
I got my peer organizations started. 
I got my cli started. 
after that request is failing with

OCI runtime exec failed:

```
exec failed: container_linux.go:348 : starting container process caused "no such file or directory": unknown
```

Comment: Need more information than the specific error. Can you please share a bit more context? Are you running one of the tutorials? Which? What version of the software? Have you modified any of the sample code/config? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

The error means that either `working_dir` is undefined, or it does not exist.
Czeck the cli section in your docker-compose file for the above setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows OS, a possible cause is the file encoding (should be in Unix format).

You could open this page:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html
And search "No such file or directory". There is some related trouble shooting.

Just a short description:
Ensure that the file in question is encoded in the Unix format. This was most likely caused by not setting `core.autocrlf` to false in your Git configuration. There are several ways of fixing this. If you have access to the vim editor for instance, open the file:

```
vim ./path/to/the/related-file
```

Then change its format by executing the following vim command:

```
:set ff=unix
```

Comment: No such file or directory is only related to shell scripts in the example you're trying to quote. "*If you see an error similar to the following: `/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`*" OP's particular problem is related to a go file, not a Unix shell script.

Comment: I had same issue, and I fixed it using dos2unix command; then the issue was the file format as this answer suggests.