# Hyperledger - container_linux.go:349 starting container process caused "no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have installed Hyperledger Fabric (2.0.0-alpha) in Docker (2.2.0.5) running on Windows (Linux containers) and am trying to start the first-network example. When running the command **./byfn.sh -m up** I am getting the following error:

```
    OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused 
    "no such file or directory": unknown ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

From the Docker Dashboard, cli and peers have started, instead of orderer. When checking the logs of the orderer I see the following error:

```
2020-05-04 20:29:04.492 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] loadVerifier -> ERRO 003 Channel byfn-sys-channel has no blocks, skipping it

    2020-05-04 20:29:04.500 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] loadVerifier -> INFO 004 Loaded verifier for channel testchainid from config block at index 0

    2020-05-04 20:29:04.520 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 005 Starting orderer with TLS enabled

    2020-05-04 20:29:04.521 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeMultichannelRegistrar -> INFO 006 Not bootstrapping because of existing chains

    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

    [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0xe06ad9]


    goroutine 1 [running]:

    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protoutil.GetMetadataFromBlock(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x194, 0x1dad440)

    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protoutil/blockutils.go:110 +0x39

    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protoutil.GetLastConfigIndexFromBlock(0x0, 0xc0002f22a0, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0)

    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protoutil/blockutils.go:130 +0x37

    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.ConfigBlock(0x7f12cf76eda8, 0xc0002f22a0, 0x7f12cf76eda8)

    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:111 +0x68

    github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.configTx(0x7f12cf76eda8, 0xc0002f22a0, 0xc0002f22a0)

    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:124 +0x35
```

I've checked for solutions online but no results till now. 
[Similar question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489157/oci-runtime-exec-failed-container-linux-go344-starting-container-process-caus) - he does not explain if he installed a new Docker version or did anything else differently. 
[Similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805205/oci-runtime-exec-failed-exec-failed-container-linux-go348-starting-containe) - in docker-compose.yml my working_dir for orderer.example.com is `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer` and for cli `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer` 
Also, my GO version is go1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue following a few steps:

1. My scripts were not working well. so I opened file script.sh and utils.sh with notepad++ and set the EOL Conversion to Linux. After this I got the following error:

> Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client
>   failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new
>   connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing:
>   dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

2. I also cleared all unused images with the following `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`
3. Bringing down the network `./byfn.sh down` and then start it again solved the issue.